# <p-multiSelect> component doesn't appear (PrimeNG 5.2.7)

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to have ap multiSelect filter in my datatable. I use  component but not appear in my page. As though there was nothing

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field">

            </p-sortIcon>
          </th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">

            <input *ngSwitchCase="'aa'" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
            <input *ngSwitchCase="'bb'" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">


            <p-multiSelect *ngSwitchCase="'cc'" [options]="cc_Item" defaultLabel="All Status"  (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'in')"></p-multiSelect>

          </th>
        </tr>

      </ng-template>
```

In my ts i have declare my item `this.cc_Item = [{label: 'my data colomn', value: 'my data column'} ... ]` and `import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';` Have you got an idea of my problem ?

Comment: Have you added `primeng.css` into your application?

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes !